# How to make some actions when timeout was reached on transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, transactions, ejb

I am maintaining code which looks like that

```
@Asynchronous
@TransactionTimeout(value = 1, unit = TimeUnit.HOUR)
public void downloadFile(Long fileId) {

    //This method takes more than 1hour
    service.download(fileId) 

    //this method should be called even when download finished with error
    service.fileDownloadedFinishedNotification(fileId);
}
```

This is just an example code, to the `fileDownloadedFinished` we are passing message which we want to display etc, and inside of that we want to mark process as finished with error/success.

So as you can see on download we can get timeout, and after that the  `fileDownloadedFinishedNotification` wont be called, because transaction failed because of the timeout.

I was thinking about extracting notification to other method and call it like this:

```
@Asynchronous
@TransactionTimeout(value = 1, unit = TimeUnit.HOUR)
public Future<String> downloadFile(Long fileId) {

    //This method takes more than 1hour
    service.download(fileId) 
    return new AsyncResult<String>("Test");
}

public void example(){
   long id = 15;
   String msg = "default stuff";

   try {
        msg = downloadFile(id).get();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   service.fileDownloadedFinishedNotification(fileId, string);

}
```

But I am not sure if it is good idea, or maybe there is some other functionality, which I can call when timeout is reaced. Something like `onTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Some considerations :

- There is no simple way to handle transaction timeout with a listener AFAIK
- Annotations use dynamic proxies under the cover, they won't so be applied on a inner call, you have to call your `downloadFile` from outside (on a bean injected in your caller).
- The current transaction will be aborted when `fileDownloadedFinishedNotification` will be called and so all operations on a transacted resource (DB, etc...) will be rolled back (you may have to invoke the method within a dedicated transaction (e.g. annotate your method with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`.
- Assuming the `download` method retrieves the content across the network and unless you access this last through a dedicated `JCA adapter`, no exception will be thrown on transaction timeout, the `Transaction reaper` only marks the current transaction as aborted and release related resources but [does not interrupt the thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/263318), **only a subsequent access to a MANAGED resource (Datasource, JMS, etc) will throw an exception**.
- Regarding the last point, while interacting with a un-managed resource the only way to know if the current transaction is still active is to regularly check its state using `EJBContext.getRollbackOnly()` or by making a dummy access to any managed resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways of achieving what you want but a proper implementation would need more information about your level of access to application change.
There are many places where transaction propagation is explained but giving you are running your app in an EJB containeer I would start from here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html

I would read it all chapter but most specific for your case is the container managed transactions here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Now assuming you have full access and you can change your database structure the way I would implemented this would be:

- You are running your service in a parent transaction T1
- Before you invoking the download method call another service to record the download started and the maximum expected time to finish. Do this in a REQUIRED_NEW transaction. This no time consuming database interaction will run in an autonomous transaction T2
- Once the above T2 transaction commits your download started record is committed and available to query
- Once back in the parent T1 start your download
- Record the success in the same record you persisted in T2 if the download successfully finishes.
- If you get a timeout the above will never be recorded and the database will still show the download as started and maximum expected time to finish
- Define a monitoring process that would kick off at regular times and check the download status. If the expected time to finish have been passed over have that monitoring process alert or record failure or trigger another retry or whatever your business rules are

Hope it helped. Sorry for not codding examples but I thing you will have enough to start with.

Cheers